# Replace second instance of string in a line in an ASCII file using Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I have an ASCII file with the following structure:

```
file1.png otherfile1.png
file2.png otherfile2.png
file3.png otherfile3.png
...
```

I want to replace `.png` with `.mat`, but only for the second column. The result should be like this:

```
file1.png otherfile1.mat
file2.png otherfile2.mat
file3.png otherfile3.mat
...
```

How do I do that in Bash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, if it is the end of the line...

```
$ sed 's/\.png$/.mat/' file
file1.png otherfile1.mat
file2.png otherfile2.mat
file3.png otherfile3.mat
```

- `s/old/new/` search and replace
- `\.` literal dot (without the escape it matches any character)
- `$` end of line

Or to explicitly specify the second column, you could use an `awk` way...

```
$ awk 'gsub(".png", ".mat", $2)' file
file1.png otherfile1.mat
file2.png otherfile2.mat
file3.png otherfile3.mat
```

- `gsub(old, new, where)` search and replace
- `$2` second column

Comment: Duh, few seconds faster than me...

Comment: Ok. I assume ` \ ` marks to search at the end of line or is this some escape symbol for `.`? What if it wasn't the end of the line? Still thanks already :)

Comment: @mcExchange sorry, I added explanation - it's the `$` that marks the end of the line in the `sed` expression

Comment: Alternatively, "s/png/mat/2" to tell sed to replace the second instance.

Comment: @Maerlyn wow, TIL!

Comment: @Maerlyn upgrade your comment to answer please, that's fascinating, gosh I did not know that about `sed` !

Answer (score 7):

You can replace all `.png` strings directly *at the end of a line* in `INPUTFILE` like this:

```
sed 's/\.png$/.mat/' INPUTFILE
```

The command above will not modify `INPUTFILE` but only print the changed version to the terminal.

To directly edit the file in place, add the `-i` flag to `sed` (or `-i.bak` to store a backup of the original file):

```
sed -i 's/\.png$/.mat/' INPUTFILE
```

Comment: still pretty fast :D